# How open custom Context Menu on Text Area Cortrol in flex?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

How i open my custom menu over right click on Text Area control, currently default menue of paste, Copy, Cut etc is opened.

Please keep in mind that i want to open custom context menu over TextArea Control of Flex.

Comment: Have you tried anything? looked in the Flex documentation? run a search for it on google? anything?

Comment: yes a lot, the context menu is open but it is default but i want to open my costume.

Comment: WHAT have you tried? would you mind posting some of it here so we can find the mistakes??

Answer (score 1):

MouseEvent.RIGHT_CLICK is a new Event that will be enabled in the newest flash player version previously it was only available in Adobe Air desktop. http://www.bytearray.org/?p=3755

It depends on what you want to show up in the menu instead of the default?

Here is a very nice tutorial on changing or adding to the right context menu atm http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3contextmenu/