# Flex TextArea autocomplete, not TextInput

Tags: apache-flex, autocomplete, textarea, flex-spark

Does anyone know of a TextArea component with autocomplete? I understand Flextras.com's Autocomplete can be reskinned as a TextArea but wouldn't know where to begin.

Comment: +1 for giving me some love. ;)  In theory, replacing the textInput with a TextArea on a custom skin should be easy [enough].  I think the problem is where to position the drop down w/ the AutoComplete suggestions; and how to replace just a 'snippet' of text.  I'd be happy to do a custom build for you if you have a budget for it!  I don't know of an existing TextArea AutoComplete component.

Comment: Hi Flextras! Really like your work and you're always here to help out so thanks :) I don't have any experience with skinning components yet but am going to tackle thiss tmw as I want to learn it. Many of the autocomplete solutions I've found this far aren't mobile optimized so your mobile autocomplete is definately what I'm going to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted to auto complete on each word, similar to (Ctrl-Space) in most IDEs, then you could try doing it yourself.

I would imagine that you would catch the change event on the text area then do some comparison (something like *startsWith*) of the characters preceding the carat against some pre-populated collection of words.

Flextras poses a good question, in how do you display suggestions. One idea would be to use a custom context menu, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645777/how-open-custom-context-menu-on-text-area-cortrol-in-flex), containing your suggestions. There's also a decision to be made on when to display it. Do you display it constantly as the user types, or maybe when they use a key combination (Ctrl-Space).

It's an interesting challenge.